# How to create an alias to bind method in Arrow-kt?

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

In Arrow-kt I'd like to create an alias to the `bind()` - for a kind of custom lib to use Arrow.

I'd expect the following to work but it doesn't:

```
suspend fun <F, S> Either<F, S>.bindMy(): S = this.bind()
```

The method I wanna target is

```
public interface EffectScope<in R> {
  ...
  public suspend fun <B> Either<R, B>.bind(): B
```

I guess it doesn't work as I expect because of the EffectScope.

Any idea how I could make it work?
Thx

Answer (score 2):

`bind` is defined in `EffectScope` or `Raise` (Arrow 2.0 snapshot) as an extension method over `Either<A, B>`.

You can go about this in different ways.

1. Use the upcoming context receivers feature if you are in JVM.

```kotlin
context(EffectScope<E>)
fun <E, A> Either<E, A>.myBind(): A = fold({ shift(it) }, ::identity)
```

2. Extend the `EffectScope` interface and define your fold machinery as Arrow does for `EffectScope` and `Effect`. Unfortunately, until context receivers are available, this is a more heavyweight solution. If you use the 2.0 snapshot, where all this is simpler, you will need to provide similar machinery like [Raise](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/39e326f47ec1a534f6fdd6cabecf50bd72d16195/arrow-libs/core/arrow-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/arrow/core/continuations/Raise.kt) and [Effect](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/39e326f47ec1a534f6fdd6cabecf50bd72d16195/arrow-libs/core/arrow-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/arrow/core/continuations/Effect.kt).

If you'd like some help with any of this, we hang out in the [Kotlin slack](https://slack.kotlinlang.org) #Arrow channel